# What is the meaning of a Falling Intonation in a yes/no question?

Tags: american-english, questions, intonation

In the question "**Did you leave an Easter egg during our interview?**" from [**this video**](https://youtu.be/VoAQv4kRwZQ?t=145) entitled, *Taylor Swift Answers Ellen's 'Burning Questions'*

> Why did Ellen DeGeneres say "**during our interview**" with a **falling intonation**
>   instead of a rising intonation **at the end of the sentence**? (see the below picture)

As I know a yes/no question should be finished with a rising intonation.

[image]

Comment: It would be extremely unusual for there to be a falling intonation in the first sentence. What makes you think that's normal? Questions almost always use a rising intonation—and it doesn't matter how the sentence introduces the question. (Yes, you may have found a video where something unusual happens; that just makes it the exception.)

Comment: Note the rising intonation on "Easter egg". That points out there is some surprise or question why an interviewee would leave *the egg*... and it could have been used as computing argot, where an "Easter egg" is a surprise in a program, such as a game hidden inside a word processor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions should usually end with a **rising** intonation.

If you also *rise* on "Easter egg" (in addition to the ending), you're putting emphasis on "Easter egg", as in asking "Was it an **Easter egg** that you left, and not something else?".

If an extra high *rise* is made on "during our interview* (mostly for emphasis), that's like asking "You did that *at that time*?"

In the provided video, it *still* sounds like a question, with a slightly different tone. It's mostly up to the situation, feeling (of the speaker), and some other small factors. It usually doesn't make a big difference. You can use falling intonation for questions, though it's usually better and easier to stick with rising.

Comment: Yeah I can understand she was emphasizing Easter Egg. But why did she say "during our interview" with a falling intonation instead of remaining the pitch after "easter egg" and raising it at the end of the sentence?

Comment: It doesn't really change the question in that case. If you're not used to it, you should just stick with rising at the end of questions.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer!

A. When you're asking a Yes/No question with a **rising intonation**, it means

1. You already know the answer but you're not so sure and you want to **check** it.

And/Or ...

2. You just **expect a short answer** (yes or no), and the person you asked can choose to explain or not explain why it is yes/ why it is no.

---

B. When you're asking a Yes/No question with a **falling intonation**, it means you're **looking for a explanation**, not simply a yes/no.

> Eg: Did you eat my cake? (Asked with a **falling intonation** => The asker
>   was likely waiting for a long explanation like the below answers)
>
> - Sorry, but yes. I had to study for the exam all night long, and then I
>     was starving but the cupboard was bare. So I had no choice. Sorry
>     about that.
> - Or: No, I didn't stay at home last night. I spent the whole night
>     cramming for my exam.

Comment: An explanation is still an **answer** to a question, an explanation (= *because*) answers a "Why" question. The word stress is more important, if I place more stress on the word ***you***, I am unsure as to the identity of the person who ate the slice of delicious cake that was mine. If I stress the word ***my*** I am asking why someone ate *my* cake because there were other pieces of cake the listener could have eaten. If I stress the word ***cake*** I am really upset because the cake was really special to me (might have been a birthday cake, or a really expensive pastry cake, who knows)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yeah, I think stress is important. But Do you agree that after the asker stress their important word, they still go down at the end of the yes/no question (**falling intonation**) to show that they want to **'know more'**?

Comment: I think, so don't quote me on this, but sometimes when someone lowers the intonation, the question sounds more like an accusation or it becomes only rhetorical. The speaker already knows the answer to the question: "Did you eat mummy's cake, Johnny?  reading between the lines the mother is saying “I know you [Johnny] did but I want you to tell me the truth.”